# Getting ProcessorInformation from CallNtPowerInformation()

Tags: winapi, system, cpu, frequency

Formerly, I was able to get the current cpu core frequencies in Windows 10, using this call:

```
    const NTSTATUS gotinfo = CallNtPowerInformation
    (
        ProcessorInformation,
        NULL,
        0,
        pinf,
        sizeof(pinf)
    );
    assert(gotinfo != ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER);
    assert(gotinfo != ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED);
    assert(gotinfo == ERROR_SUCCESS);
```

But when I try that today, I always see 3700Mhz returned for both Max and Cur freq on my core i5 12600k, for all cores. This is incorrect. The function returns SUCCESS status, but yields incorrect results.

What happened here? Why did [CallNtPowerInformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/powerbase/nf-powerbase-callntpowerinformation) stop working?

NOTE: [Microsoft forgot to include the struct definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/power/processor-power-information-str) for PROCESSOR_POWER_INFORMATION, and tells you do define it yourself. They claimed it would be fixed in new versions of WINNT.H but it never was.

Comment: @HansPassant No, it is incorrect, it never changes. In addition, it shows the same for all cores, which is incorrect also. The P cores and E cores have a different max frequency for 12600k. It returns the base clock as max/cur for all cores.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft has silently removed the functionality from the API.

https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-Dev-Performance/issues/100